# Blacklist the "command" tag?

Tags: discussion, tag-block-request

[command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command) is not a helpful tag. Currently, 3 questions are tagged [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command).

The subject of these questions looks like "What is the command for ...?". These questions will be fine with the tag [shell-scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting), so my suggestion is to remove the [command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command) tag.

Comment: [Those questions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line) are mostly not bash-specific anyhow.  bash is not the only shell.

Comment: @poolie: shell-scripting then?

Comment: I think if the question is actually about how to program the shell, like [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30449), then `shell-scripting` is appropriate, and for some "how do I do foo in bash" perhaps `bash` is appropriate.  But if it's just something like [Torrent client for the command-line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/29872/1116) then the fact that you're running it through a shell is really irrelevant.

Comment: @poolie: I understand your point, I meant that the tag is ambiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why blacklist? At 3 tags it's not exactly a revolution. That's small enough that you could just *edit* them out.

Comment: Done -- replaced with 'command-line' where appropriate.

Comment: I've misunderstood the purpose of blacklisting then, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Command and command-line-interface (which is the tooltip hint for command-line) aren't synonyms.

A command might be a shell build-in or a program-execution, which means parameters, arguments and such.

```
find /home -type f -name bar -execdir echo {} ";"
```

is a command, where *find* is the program name. Inside the program there is another command executed, named 'echo', and since it is called from find, not from the shell itself, is the external program, not the shell build-in.

There are lots of places, where a command is issued without shell.

If you want a sweet little command executed, you may need the syntax and some options explained, but whether it is called from find, from a command-line or gedit is another topic. It can be meaningful, but it needn't.